# How to bind checkboxes and radio buttons in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: asp.net-core

This is how I want my form to look:

[image: Form Image]

This is how I want my database to store the values:

[image: Database Table Image]

What will be the model, controller and view code for adding a new book to the table?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? SO isn't a free code-writing service - **YOU** need to show your own efforts, and explain where you've gotten stuck. .... we'll help - but we won't just write the whole code for you ....

Comment: Hi @Aritra Paul, it is better for you to share enough code to us. Any way I have shared a simple demo below you could follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MininumAge { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Genres { get; set; }
    public string? Type { get; set; }
}
```

View(Create.cshtml):

```
@model Book

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Genres" class="control-label"></label>
                <div>
                    Action<input type="checkbox" name="GenresList" value="Action"/>
                    Adventure<input type="checkbox" name="GenresList" value="Adventure" />
                    Thriller<input type="checkbox" name="GenresList" value="Thriller"/>
                    Horror<input type="checkbox" name="GenresList" value="Horror" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Genres" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label"></label>
                <div>
                    Fiction<input type="radio" asp-for="Type" value="Fiction" />
                    Non-Fiction<input type="radio" asp-for="Type" value="Non-Fiction"/>
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Type" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MininumAge" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="MininumAge" class="form-control">
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="34">34</option>
                    <option value="45">45</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="MininumAge" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class BooksController : Controller
{
    private readonly MvcProj6_0Context _context;

    public BooksController(MvcProj6_0Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }        
    // GET: Books/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Books/Create        
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Book book,List<string> GenresList)
    {
        //you will get the checkbox list by GenresList parameter
        //convert list string to string with comma
        string Genres = string.Join(",", GenresList);
        book.Genres = Genres;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(book);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(book);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]